# seekBar and refresh

Tags: android

I've a seekBar and I can increase and decrease text size but I've a problem: when I change tha value by seekBar and press a button (x++) new TextSwitched is ok but if again I press I've old value (text decreased). Pressing again I've new value... Reading logs values doesn't change when I press button. Value changes only when use seekBar. Thanks for patience.

```
seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
          public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          if(seek<10)
          {
          seek=10;
          seekBar1.setProgress(seek);
          }

          }
          public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          }
          public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          seek=progress;

          TextView t = (TextView) mSwitcher.getChildAt(0); 
          t.setTextSize(seek);
          Log.i("MyActivity", "MyClass.getView() — list " + seek);

          SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PRIVATE_PREF, 0);
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
          editor.putInt("seek", seek);
          editor.putInt("progress", progress);
          editor.commit();
```

Button:

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    x++;
                    mSwitcher.setText(""+prog[x]);
```

public View makeView() {
    TextView t = new TextView(this);

```
return t;
```

Comment: Where's the code for the Button, and its onClickListener?

Comment: I uploaded my code, thanks.

Comment: I guess the SeekBar is pissed that you didn't paste the whole OnClickListener code, and just restarts in rebellion.

Comment: I think there is a problem with method public View makeView(). What do u think? :-)